# Rendering text after fetching data from database using React and AWS Amplify

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I am trying to use React and AWS Amplify to build a web app that will make a request to the database and display some text accordingly. However, I encounter the following error:

Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

The error message also indicates that the error is occurring after `setNfts(nftList);`

App.jsx:

```
function App() {

  const [nfts, setNfts] = useState([]);

  const fetchNfts = async () => {
    try {
        const nftData = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(listNfts));
        const nftList = nftData.data.listNfts.items;
        console.log('nft list', nftList);
        setNfts(nftList);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error on fetching nfts', error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchNfts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <AmplifySignOut />
        <h2>My App Content</h2>
      </header>

      <Box sx={{ display: 'grid', columnGap: 3, gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(3, 1fr)' }}>
        {nfts.map((nft, idx) => {
          return (
            <NftCard filePath={nft.filePath} name={nft.name} creator={nft.creator} idx={idx} />
          );
        })}
      </Box>
    </div>
  );
}
```

NftCard.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Paper } from '@material-ui/core';

export function NftCard(filePath, name, creator, idx) {

    return(
        <Paper variant="outlined" elevation={2} key={`nft${idx}`}>
            <div className="nftCard">
                <div>
                    <img src={filePath} alt="" width="100px" height="100px" />
                    <div className="nftTitle">{name}</div>
                    <div className="nftCreator">{creator}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Paper>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The props passed to NftCard should be listed separately and have curly braces around them:

```
function NftCard({ filePath, name, creatorThumbnail, creator, price, idx }) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log('nft list', nftList);
```

Does this have any data logged out?

And if so, can you please provide output?

Comment: 0:
createdAt: "2021-09-14T17:16:14.075Z"
creator: "Beeple"
description: "Together we can solve this."
filePath: "https://nft-storage131929-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/public/beeple-03-23-19.jpg"
id: "gr4334t4tog345ht35"
name: "Ocean Front"
price: 35
updatedAt: "2021-09-14T17:16:14.075Z"
[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: Looks to me that you are trying to iterate through Object?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to send data to Component with:

```
<NftCard filePath={nft["0"].filePath} name={nft["0"].name} creator={nft["0"].creator} idx={idx} />
```

and Show the result of that